# Parent and child entities in one to one relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

The entity which participates in the 1:0+ relationship is the parent entity.

Is that correct?

Update:

[image: Image provided]

Comment: What 1:1 relationship are you talking about?

Comment: A 1:1 relationship means one table -- no relationship, it's optimized to be a single entity.  It can be a performance improvement to model a 1:1 table relationship, but that's the only reason for these existing.  Direction of the relationship is only established by the foreign key definition - it's either one way, or the other.

Comment: @OMGPonies I think he's talking about 1:1 optional relationship, i.e. one to zero or one.

Comment: @Polynomial: Yes, I've re-read & you are correct.  This is a poorly worded question.

Comment: Sorry for the poorly worded question. MY knoweldge is still pretty muddled =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is wrong.

In a 1:1 relationship, you just have one table. There's no distinction. The attributes *must* apply to both types of entity.

However, in an optional 1:1 relationship, often called 1:0+ or "one to zero or one" relationship, the child would be the optional one, not the parent.

In short, there will *always* be a parent.

---

In your image, there's an optional one-to-one from staff to notebook, i.e. a staff member may have zero notebooks or one notebook. There's also a one-to-one relationship from notebook to staff, i.e. a notebook must have exactly one member of staff as an owner.

Here's a diagram to help you understand:

[image: Crow's Foot]

Comment: In the image I just uploaded, the optional symbol actually belongs to Staff relation instead of Notebook relation right ? That's why I am confused. My notes mentioned this for that particular image - The entity that optionally participates is the parent entity.

Comment: @TheKraven That's not how it reads to me. A notebook must have one owner. A staff member may optionally have a notebook. Remember that the crow's feet notation works in the *direction* of ownership, not on the side of the parent. Pages 12 and 13 of [this PDF](http://jackzheng.net/teaching/cis3730/files/1.5-erd.pdf) should help explain Crow's Foot notation for optional relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. My mind is slowly clearing up..
 In this case, is A the parent entity ?

Comment: Yes, A is the parent entity in this case.